# Can we use jslink for builtin application pages for specific type of lists?

Tags: 2013, javascript, css, application-pages, jslink

Can we use JSLink for built-in application pages for specific type of Lists?

What possible ways we can add CSS and JS to specific out of box List application pages?

May can use JSlink?

Comment: You mean assign a JSLink file to a particular custom list?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the JSlink property using the server side object model.

Exemple:

```
 
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
    SPField taskPriorityField = web.Fields["Priority"];

    taskPriorityField.JSLink = "/_layouts/15/TestJslink/TestJsLink.js";
    taskPriorityField.Update(true);
}
```

For CSS :

you have specific files in the solution that will be deployed in the virtual file /_Layout.

For more informations : 
[Informations MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee231578.aspx)

Yours